# Problemas con dompdf->download y dompdf->stream

Tags: laravel, dompdf, navegador-web

tengo este código que lo hale de una pagina, estoy usando laravel 7 y dompdf ver 8.x el inconveniente es el siguiente, cuando utilizo return $pdf->save, el archivo se descarga en el directorio correspondiente, pero cuando intento darle, $pdf->download no me pide descargarlo, y cuando le doy pdf->stream tampoco funciona por qué se da esto? No se si será problema de mi navegador, mi pc o qué.

```
$pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Hola mundo</h1>');
return $pdf->save('mi-archivo.pdf');
```

Pd. si pudieran ayudarme a como customizar el tamaño del papel también se los voy a agradecer.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera, usando [streamDownload](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#streamed-downloads), en tu componente deberías tener un método que será el que se ejecutará cuando se presione el botón de descargar:

```
public function downloadPDF()
{
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.invoice');
    return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($pdf) {
        echo $pdf->stream();
    }, 'invoice.pdf'); 
}
```

Básicamente obtienes el PDF en un stream() y retornas una `downloadable response`.

En tu vista deberías tener algo así:

```
<div>
    <button wire:click="downloadPDF">
        Download File
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, tuve que adaptarlo ya que en esta parte no estoy usando livewire, pero todo bien, gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Creo haber leído que tu pregunta incluía livewire. Pero si dices que no incluye livewire, sólo basta con que tu ruta sea tipo GET y retornar un download haría el trabajo